# Git: Reset Network Graphs

Tags: git, github

I would like to know if there is a way to reset network graph of your repository status in Git. I have an assignment which will be highly tracked by the Network graph.In addition to this,I would like to delete the history of the commits what have been made by me.  I am too concerned about it

FYI ::  Network graph is located at 
Insights tab -> Network tab.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. 
It's called "squashing commits", and you can read about it here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Comment: I have a quick question. 

I want to revert the commit back to previous commit as I uploaded wrong files and want those changes to get reflected in the Network graph as well .. Does

"git revert  <commitid>"  and after this      "git push origin master"

Will reset my network graph to previous state?

I am too concerned about this as this is a part of my assignment where network graph matters a lot. Please help. Its urgent .

Comment: What you're looking for is a hard reset - see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset for how to do that. You want to reset to the last commit before you uploaded the wrong files.

Comment: OK , so are telling to execute  "git reset --hard  HEAD^"  and then "git push origin master"   . After doing it,  will it reflect in the Network graph as well ? I am sorry to bother but I am quite tense as this is a part of my assignment. I am newbie and I messed up things and do it want to do any mistake further..  can you give me step by step instructions?

Comment: Yes, with one minor difference: you have to force the push, like so: `git push -f origin master `

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to do it successfully